# How do I copy music from ipod nano to computer (Banshee)

Tags: banshee, nano

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04. My Nano syncs fine with Banshee. How do I copy the music already on the Nano onto my computer? There doesn't seem to be an option to do this within Banshee. Also if I open the Nano in Nautilus no music files show up to copy.

Answer (score 1):

To copy tracks resident on the iPod back onto a PC use [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Advanced_features) (click [here to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtkpod)).